# POST https://api.parse.com/1/users 400 (Bad Request) ERROR when using Fb login button (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

Followed the FaceBook /Parse guide for letting users login via Fb, getting this message currently? I've looked for other examples, but can't see anything else that looks relevant.

Has anyone come across and solved this before?

```
POST https://api.parse.com/1/users 400 (Bad Request)b._ajax.j @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:1b._ajax @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:1c.extend.then.e @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:3c.extend.then.g @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:3c.extend.then @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:3b._request @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:1(anonymous function) @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:3c.extend.then.e @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:3(anonymous function) @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:3c.extend.then.g @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:3c.extend.then @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:3c.extend._continueWith @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:3c.extend.save @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:3b.User.b.Object.extend.save @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:5b.User.b.Object.extend._linkWith @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:5b.User.b.Object.extend._linkWith.a.authenticate.success @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:5g.authenticate.FB.login.scope @ parse-1.4.2.min.js:5window.FB.u.__wrapper @ all.js:95(anonymous function) @ all.js:91window.FB.ha._xdRecv @ all.js:113(anonymous function) @ all.js:113pa @ all.js:90(anonymous function) @ all.js:88window.FB.h.setWrapper.j @ all.js:50window.FB.h.setWrapper.j @ all.js:50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused my the fact that I'd deleted the Fb app and created a new one and not switched over the secret question and app id in the parse.com back end. Bit stupid to forget this, but someone else might find this handy one day..